# my ionic framework project has been reject from Apple review team

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, local-storage

I'm developer who develop iOS app with ionic framework, my app was rejected by apple review team for data storage guideline reason. They said **"On launch and content download, your app stores 8.56 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines."**

[image]

as you can see, my app keeps .json files (size 9.8 MB) which contains persist data using on my app.

Then I write the code like

```
$http.get('js/query/sura_'+$scope.sura_id+'.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.aya  = data;
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            check_file_exist();
        });
```

to get data from .json files and show on the app.

I think this would be the reason why my app has been rejected. So I would like to ask you how to change the way to store large data on to the app by following Apple guideline. please suggest me and show me sample code.

Thank you.

Comment: can you compress and convert to binary and on front end retrieve and convert to json

Comment: Where do you put your Json files, `Documents Directory`?

Comment: You can put all your json files into a folder, and add `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to the folder. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html), how..

Comment: @iphonic I put my JSON files on "/js/query/" folder. I don't know how can I use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey with ionic framework project.

Comment: @Giffary you don't need to put the key with the ionic framework check the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html you need to add this for the folder that is `/js/query/` programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is not scalable, one day you will need to add more `sura_id` files, and this is time to persist your data, into a database, a good suggestion will be `MongoDB` and access it with an API..., in this way you will not need to resend for validation of your application.

The minus will be of course the `needed INTERNET connection` for you application to connect to the api